# Java - Pixel extends occasionally

Tags: java, image, canvas, pixel

I am currently trying to make my first, very basic, 2D game engine in Java for use in the next Ludum Dare, which I hope to participate in. I am, however, experiencing a visual distortion (no exception is thrown) when rendering to the canvas. Occasionally, in what appears to be a grid, a pixel in my image (which has been scaled up for the game) extends on the x or y axis. ex: An image pixel which was supposed to occupy a 2x2 area on the screen now occupies 2x3, 3x2, or 3x3 instead.

This is the class I am using to render the pixels:

```
public class Renderer
{
    private int width, height;
    private int[] pixelArray;
    public Renderer(GameContainer gc)
    {
        width = gc.getWidth();
        height = gc.getHeight();
        pixelArray = ((DataBufferInt)gc.getWindow().getImage().getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    }

    public void setPixel(int x, int y, int color)
    {
        if(x <0 || x > width || y < 0 || y > height) return;

        pixelArray[x + (y* width)] = color;
    }

    public void renderImage(Image image, int offsetX, int offsetY)
    {
    for(int x = 0; x < image.width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < image.height; y++)
            {
                setPixel(x + offsetX, y + offsetY, image.pixels[x + (y * image.width)]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearScreen()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)    
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                setPixel(x, y, 0xff000000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Image` is my own class (not the `AWT` one) that loads the image to be displayed and  contains height and width variables, as well as a 2D array of the RGB values for each pixel.

I hope this is enough information for someone to help with the problem. If any more is needed just let me know.

Comment: Do you get an exception or is it just a visual error?
Edit: At the beginning it sounded like you are getting an exception when drawing on the canvas. But the 2x3 instead of 2x2 part sounds like a visual error.

Comment: Yeah, there's no exception, it's just a visual error.

Comment: I dont see any mistakes in the code snippet. Have you tested (with println's) if image.width and image.height are correct?

Comment: Yup. both the width and the height print out to the correct value.

Comment: Hmm maybe you have some sort of after image? In the form of:  clear image -> draw figure -> move figure -> draw figure . If that also isn't the case, I am out of idead, sry =/ edit: or it is a scaling problem, if you are scaling the image on displaying it?

Comment: Yes, I scale the entire canvas by a factor of 2 (can be changed via a float in the code).

Comment: Do you know if the error remains without the scaling?

Comment: Just tested it without scaling (omitted the operation altogether) and the error still appears.